# Como gravar conteudo em uma session em asp classico e passar para uma página mvc?

Tags: session, asp, checkbox

Como gravar o check do `checkbox` em uma `session` para poder usá-la em outra página ? É possível ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só complementando as repostas existe outra propriedade do ASP que se chama "Application" e ele tem basicamente a mesma função do "Session" ou seja guardar um valor de forma global, porém a diferença entre elas é que "Session" é aplicada somente a um usuário e o "Application" funciona para todos os usuários.

```
<%
Application("usuario")="João"
Application("idade")=50

Response.Write Application("usuario") & " - " & Application("idade")
%>
```

Referencias:
 
[Applications W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_applications.asp)
[MSDN Application e Sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952597.aspx)

Comment: ajudou bastante também, só que vi aqui que o problema é outro, eu não tenho o fonte do projeto e ele está misturado, uma parte em asp classico e outra em mvc, preciso passar o valor do checkbox pra uma página em mvc. Sabe como posso fazer isso ? E também não queria gravar no banco.

Answer (score 3):

Veja o código abaixo:

Página default.asp

```
<body>
<form method="post" method="sessao.asp">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="1234"> Enviar o valor 1234 deste checkbox.<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Página sessao.asp

```
<%
'Recebe o valor do checkbox e atribui a sessão.
session("ckb") = request.form("ckb")
response.write(session("ckb"))
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Neste [link](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp) você poderá ter toda a documentação de utilização de sessão com asp.

Segue um breve exemplo:

```
<%
Session("usuario")="João"
Session("idade")=50
%>
```

Espero ter ajudado.